# React component that change of column are remounted/rerendered with dynamically generated columns

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here you have my current obsession in a codesandbox. I'm generating columns dynamically depending on screen width to distribute an array of components. Works, but when I resize the screen to change the number of columns, the components are reordered correctly but all the components that change of column are re-rendered.

Resizing screen you'll see in console log that components that change of column are remounted (makes sense). I want to know if there's a way to avoid that (at this point, I'm afraid not with this approach).

After many different tries with useRef, useMemo, etc. (some of them probably crazy, but I had to try), my conclusion so far is that with this approach the component has to be removed from one column and added to the other, so is going to be rerendered no matter what.

Any ideas?

https://codesandbox.io/s/28n127vnj

Comment: can you achieve the layout with CSS `grid` without changing JS state? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Yes, I think I could solve it with grid. I was trying to avoid it because grid is usually a problem with old browsers support. And I'm also curious if it's posible to do this in React. In fact, it is, I think I've solved it using Portals. I'll post the results probably today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally a combination of Portals and refs came to the rescue and did the trick.

In the end, this was a reparenting problem, and doing some research I found out this facebook issue...

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13044

... where `vkatushenok` gives a great solution to this problem. Taking that idea and adapting it a little bit, allow me to find a way to solve it.

Just in case you have this situation or similar, here you have how I solve it...

https://codesandbox.io/s/kwr0vn6x15